# After JSON.parse the result shown is "Object"

Tags: json, node.js, azure, azure-bot-service

I've created a bot using azure bot service, when I give it an api call, my bot replies "Object" instead of the output required.

I have also tried `json.stringify()`, it doesn't show any output in the online test chat and shows an error on the channels page : Gateway timeout and when I tried the bot out in Skype it showed an error: `Message size to large`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlRly.png)

Comment: That's because you're calling `toString()`.

Comment: So what should i call?

Comment: That depends on what you actually want to display.